# Regular Expression: Consecutive Repetitions with a Letter In Between

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to solve a problem with regular expressions. I am using Java regex which is similar to that in Perl apparently.

I want to search for a string that has a single digit from 1-9, repeating 3 or more times consecutively or with the single letter 'w' between repetitions.

For eg. 12333, 123w3, 12ww3, ww123 should all give successful matches but not 12345, 1234w, 1323w.

I tried the pattern "[[0-9]w]{3,}" but I now understand why that is definitely incorrect. Can someone give me a few clues to constructing the search pattern that fits my requirements?

Comment: How do `123w3`, `12ww3` and `ww123` match your requirement? The first case there is only 2 3's, in the second case there are no repeated digits and in the third case the `w` isn't between any numbers.

Comment: I find this difficult to understand.  And why isn't `1323w` valid (it has 33w)? Is `12ww3` same as `12223`, or as `12333`? What about `123ww`?

Comment: Please clarify the criteria for a match.

Comment: Dont' understand why the question is not clear to people. It's quite straight forward. `222` is valid, and then replace one or any two 2's with `w`, and then it's valid, e.g. - `w2w, ww2, 22w, 2ww`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly that `w` is a wildcard (because I am not sure from what you have written - more by the examples you give) then this regex should work...

```
([1-9])(\1|w){2,}|w([1-9])(\3|w)+|ww([1-9])\5*
```

This is maybe not the most elegant solution, but should work, and breaks into parts like this...

```
           # matches that don't start with wildcards
([1-9])    # get a digit, and capture for future reference
(\1|w){2,} # the captured digit, or the letter w, 2 or more times
|          # or, matches that start with a single w
w          # match a w
([1-9])    # get a digit, and capture for future reference
(\3|w)+    # get one or more of the captured digit, or letter w
|          # or, matches starting with two w
ww         # get two w
([1-9])    # get a digit, and capture for future reference
\5*        # get all the successive captured digits
```

This should also work...

```
([1-9])(\1|w){2,}|w([0-9](\3|w)|w[0-9])
```

Comment: The numbers are a little off, you want something like `([0-9])(?:\1|w){2}|w([0-9])(?:\2|w)|ww([0-9])`. Note that `\1` is always the first group - `([0-9])` - and is empty when the first alternation doesn't match.

Comment: @BillyMoon Yup, that was exactly what I was looking for. I would also like to appreciate you taking the time to split the solution into parts. That was important to me as I am only beginning to learn regular expressions. Thanks a ton!